# Как программно аутентифицировать пользователя по сессии Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, auth, vaadin

Я знаю, что в спринг уже встроен такой механизм при отправке запроса по маршруту /login или другому выбранному в WebSecurityConfig'e. Также если брать Vaadin, то в нём есть специальный компонент LoginForm, аутентификация через него описана [тут](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/tutorial/login-and-authentication). Как вы понимаете мне не нужен стандартный механизм, так как я хочу:

- сделать одинаково другой дизайн как для страницы регистрации так и для входа.
- добавить что-то типа прохождения капчи или отправки кода для проверки подлинности на электронную почту.

Одним словом - кастомизировать механизм входа.

Как программно аутентифицировать пользователя?

Я пробовал такое решение:

```java
try {
    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(fieldMail.getValue(), fieldPassword.getValue()); // mail и password
    Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication); // authenticationManager был получен через @Autowired из бина
    if (authenticatedUser.isAuthenticated()) { // проверка на аутентифицированность
        System.out.println("One user authenticated");
        UI.getCurrent().navigate("x1/cabinet"); // переходим в кабинет пользователя
    }
        credentialsErrorText.setVisible(false); // показываем ошибку данных входа
}catch (BadCredentialsException e){
    credentialsErrorText.setVisible(true); // показываем ошибку данных входа
}
```

Bean:

```java
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration){
        try {
            return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Но не помогло. Удивительно, но ошибки нет!
Когда я ввожу действительные данные и нажимаю - войти, то в консоли пишет, что юзер в базе данных найден и успешно получен, да ещё и аутентифицирован:

```
user found
from user
One user authenticated
```

Но на сайте это не отображается, так как при нажатии "войти" меня на миллисекунду отправляет в кабинет, но потом снова возвращает на страницу входа как будто я ещё не аутентифицировался, так как в кабинет можно только аутентифицированным пользователям (@PermitAll).

PS. Продолжая поиски решения я пришёл к такому коду:

```java
                try {
                    SecurityUser principal = new SecurityUser(
                            fieldPassword.getValue().toString(),fieldMail.getValue().toString(), true,
                            new HashSet<>(){{
                                add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("User"));
                            }});
                    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            principal,
                            new Credentials() {
                        @Override
                        public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                            return (Principal) principal;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public String getPassword() {
                            return fieldPassword.getValue().toString();
                        }
                    },principal.getAuthorities());
                    Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);

                    if (authenticatedUser.isAuthenticated()) {
                        System.out.println("One user authenticated");
                        UI.getCurrent().navigate("x1/cabinet");
                    }
                }catch (BadCredentialsException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Notification.show("CredentialsError");
                }
```

В итоге при верных входных данных срабатывает catch BadCredentialsException при вызове метода authenticationManager.authenticate()

Comment: Пожалуйста, прежде чем дизлайкать, в комментариях укажите причину, чтобы мне было куда совершенствоваться

Comment: Да почти любой вопрос по Спрингу стабильно минусуют, особенно если он сложный. Тут это обычное дело)